# Dust.js - partial extend base

Tags: javascript, node.js, dust.js

I use NodeJS as engine to dust.
I have problem with partials. I think that it is possible, what I want.
Here is my index.dust :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Project - {title}</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
    {>"common/navbar-logout"/}
    {+content /}
</div>
    {+scripts /}
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to "import" common/navbar-logout file.
In "common/navbar-logout" file, I have:

```
{>"index" /}
{! some HTML!}
{<scripts}
<script>
    console.log("yyyy");
</script>
{/scripts}
```

When I run this script, I've got:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded    at
>   Object.dust.filters.h
>   (/APP_PATH/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:296:16)    at
>   Object.dust.filter
>   (/APP_PATH/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:290:34)    at
>   Chunk.reference
>   (/APP_PATH/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:764:30)    at
>   body_0 (evalmachine.:1:371)    at load
>   (/APP_PATH/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:151:14)    at
>   Chunk.partial
>   (/APP_PATH/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:911:14)    at
>   body_0 (evalmachine.:1:157)    at load
>   (/APP_PATH/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:151:14)    at
>   Chunk.partial
>   (/APP_PATH/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:911:14)    at
>   body_0 (evalmachine.:1:661)    at load
>   (/APP_PATH/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:151:14)    at
>   Chunk.partial
>   (/APP_PATH/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:911:14)    at
>   body_0 (evalmachine.:1:157)    at load
>   (/APP_PATH/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:151:14)    at
>   Chunk.partial
>   (/APP_PATH/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:911:14)    at
>   body_0 (evalmachine.:1:661)

When I remove **{>"index" /}** in **"common/navbar-logout"**, application run, but I don't have script block from **"common/navbar-logout"** in **"index"** .

**My goal is inject script-block from "common/navbar-logout" into "index" using partial "{>"common/navbar-logout"/}"**

Answer (score 0):

Dust partials can only provide blocks to templates that they include into themselves. Instead of `index` requiring `common/navbar-logout`, you would have to have `common/navbar-logout` include `index` as a partial. It could then supply its inline partials to the blocks in `index`. This doesn't lend itself well to your use case.

To accomplish what you actually want to do, I've used some custom helpers in the past. Something like this:

```
{! some HTML!}
{@script}
    console.log("yyyy");
{/script}

dust.helpers.script = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  if (params.src) {
    addScript(params.src); // adds to some global context var
  } else {
    chunk = chunk.write('<script>').render(bodies.block, context).write('</script>');
  }
  return chunk;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work as I want. It adds script on the end of "common/navbar-logout" but not on the end of "index" (in script extend).

I think, that I don't achieve what I want. I have to do in another way.